# Shorthand for accessing values from params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I often feel the need to access the individual key-value pairs from the 'params' hash, as if they were local variables.

I find that using local variables instead of writing 'params' every time, makes my code easier to  understand.

So instead of using the values like `params[:first_variable]` I would do something like :

```
first_var  = params[:first_variable]

second_var = params[:second_variable]
...
```

and in my program i would use this short notation instead of writing `params[:first_var]` every time.

The problem with this is that the size of my functions can grow significantly, when I have many values in params.

Is there a better way to reference the objects from 'params' as local variables in my function ?

Comment: Can you explain this with some code? Controllers should not be doing any funky work, usually you just get the params hash and give it to someone else to work on it, you shouldn't really have to define lots of local variables on controllers and if you do it probably means your controller is doing much more than what it would be doing.

Comment: http://www.stephenchu.com/2008/03/paramfu-1-wrap-all-relevant-attributes.html

Comment: I don't think this makes your code any easier to understand without having to fully explain it to someone joining your project(?).  but this is just a humble opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* redefine `method_missing` in which class you want this functionality. If you do, remember the cardinal rules of `method_missing` - if you can't handle it, call pass it on (to `super`); and update `respond_to?` in parallel.

Something like this, perhaps.

```
class Foo
  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    if params.include? name
      params[:name]
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to?(name)
    if params.include? name
      true
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Remember that Rails makes heavy use of `method_missing` already, so either only redefine it on your own classes, or alias the existing version and call that instead of `super` when you aren't handling.

Comment: +1 but could be dangerous depending on params' variable names

Comment: Don't do that. Haven't we learned better from PHP's register_global? http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals